# ffmpeg won't start until java exits

Tags: java, ffmpeg, runtime, wait

I am trying to make a java program that automatically converts wtv files in an input folder to mpg files in output folder.  The twist is that I make it run periodically, so it acts as a synchronizer.

The following code works for converting the .wtv to a .dvr-ms, which is required by ffmpeg since it cannot convert .wtv files directly.

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\ehome\\WTVConverter C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\test\\input\\input.wtv C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\test\\output\\input.dvr-ms");
    p.waitFor();
```

WTVConverter has no problems running from a java application.  ffmpeg is a different story.  Once the above line runs, I then run this...

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg -y -i \"C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\test\\output\\input.dvr-ms'" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f dvd \"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\test\output\input.mpg\"");
    p.waitFor();
```

Suddenly, there is a problem...  The application ffmpeg shows up in the task manager, but it's cpu usage is 0, and no mpeg files is being generated.  If I force the java application to close, though, suddenly it starts working!  Huh?

What reason would there be for a command line application to wait for its calling application to quit before it executes?  I'm not incredibly command line savvy, so I don't really know how to diagnose this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Bah, this always happens.  I post a question, and THEN I figure it out on my own.  Turns out, ffmpeg expects you to read in its text output before it loads each frame.  If a calling program does not do this, it simply waits.  If there is no calling program, I assume that it just outputs it nowhere.  What I did is ran the program as usual, but also read in text from the process's input stream like so...

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(".....");
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
    new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        }
    }.start();
```

Lesson learned, I guess.